# Load post response into existing html page

Tags: express, post

all:

I have an API call using express and I'm wanting the data to load into an existing paragraph tag on the html page with the form, but currently it loads into a new html page using res.send(). Have checked the express documentation and cannot find anything. Any ideas how I can do this? Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
const port = 3000;
const request = require('request');


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
})

app.post("/", (req, res)=>{

    let crypto = req.body.crypto;

    let fiat = req.body.fiat;

    request(`https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/${crypto}${fiat}`, function (error, response, body) {

    let data = JSON.parse(body);

    let price = data.last;

    res.write(`<h1>${price}</h1>`);

});
})



app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
})
```

Thank you all so much,

Kevin

Comment: I dont really get why you put this through express. I mean you could write a direct fetch request from the html page await it and update the dom. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Yeah...it's a project that I'm doing for a course on Udemy. The instructor uses express.